# Redirect http to https except frontpage page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have been trying to redirect all url `http` to `https` except frontpage. I have done for specific `url` i.e. `sign-in` but I need to do it for homepage. Please see below what I did:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sign-in [NC] // don't understand what should be for hompage instead of sign-in
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/sign-in [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

It would be greatest help if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Place these 2 rules above all the other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect home page to http://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect anything but home page to https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# rest of your rules go here
```

Comment: it does not work. It redirects all pages to `https`. Thanks for answered in this question too. FYI: I don't call `index.php` for home page. This project is written in drupal 7.

Comment: I have slightly modified it. Make sure these rules are **before** all other rules as I had suggested in answer. Completely clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: thanks for you effort. Still not working. I want, all the page should be redirected to `https` except homepage/fontpage. I have done myself but want to see your solution.

Comment: `RewriteRule .` will only match something which is not the landing page. I've tested these rules on my Apache and everything is working fine. `http://localhost` doesn't redirect to `https://`. Only way it cannot work if some other rules override these 2 rules.